# What to return to loop through a function return

Tags: php

I am currently trying to loop through a return from a function, but I just haven't been able to figure out how to do this. It's a bit like the Wordpress loop: while (have_posts()).

That is what I am trying to do, but what do my function have to return to be while-loopable?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you mean.  What are you looping?  What are you returning?  Can you show some pseudo-code that demonstrates conceptually what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @David I think the thing is, I don't know what I have to loop. What I wan't to know is, what a function has to return to make it loopable?

Comment: arrays,objects, ... this is too generic question. Question is what did you try so far?

Comment: David did make a great answer to this. I can see that my question is very unclear, I am sorry guys. But David got it, and that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Kolind: No need to apologize :)  Often it's difficult to frame a question when one is new to the very terminology being used.  Glad we could help, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just asking what `have_posts()` returns in this case?

It's not "a loopable function", it's just a function.  There's nothing about it that indicates a loop.  It's being *used* in this case as the condition for a loop:

```
while (have_posts())
```

The `while` loop condition is expecting a boolean.  Think of the statement as "while this condition is true, keep looping."  So in this case `have_posts()` should return a boolean, true or false.

As long as the function is returning `true` the loop will continue.  As soon as it returns `false` the loop will end.  The function itself has no internal knowledge of this.  It's just being called over and over (each time the loop iterates).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well (your question is not very clear), you can return an array from inside your function and then do a "foreach" loop:

```
function num($arg) {
    return array (1, 2, 3, 4);
}

foreach (num($var) as $number) {
    ...
}
```